# Linq compare string date

Tags: c#, linq

I want to compare string which is date. I am trying following linq query, but I get operators can be applied to operands of type string to string.

```
    var descriptions = 
        from a in db.Descriptions 
        where a.ID == 12  
        && a.arrivalDate >= "20110101000000" 
        && a.arrivalDate <= "20110131000000" 
        select a;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why can't you cast them to `DateTime`?

Comment: YOu will have to convert the Left ahand side and right hand side to the same Date Type

Comment: is the datatype of "a.arrivalDate" a string, or a DateTime ?

Comment: Can or cannot? Given `arrivalDate` is a `string` it should work fine.

Comment: @Dave: a.arrivalDate is of string type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot compare a `DateTime` variable with a `String` variable.

So you need to create a `DateTime` first:

```
String str1 = "20110101000000";
String str2 = "20110131000000";
String format = "yyyyMMddhhmmss";
DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(str1, format,null);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.ParseExact(str2, format, null);
```

and the LINQ query:

```
var descriptions = 
    from a in db.Descriptions
    let arrivalDate = DateTime.ParseExact(a.arrivalDate, format,null)
    where a.ID == 12  
    && arrivalDate  >= date1
    && arrivalDate  <= date2
    select a;
```

Comment: Thanks but a.arrivalDate is of string type, which contains date in the format 20110101000000. In this case, what should I do? Any idea?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why parse all the substrings, instead of DateTime.ParseExact?  And, since he is hard-coding the dates (in the example, anyway), why parse at all?

Comment: Why are you storing DateTimes as strings? Apart from that you could simpply do the same as above. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @user736074: Why are you storing DateTimes as strings? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @WonkotheSane: Thanks, i've just forgotten DateTime.ParseExact, edited my answer.

Comment: @Tim: Actually, I did not design the tables which is a part of a system. I am only using the tables to get some desired values.

Answer (score 2):

```
var descriptions = db.Descriptions.Where(a => 
                     a.ID == 12 && 
                     a.arrivalDate >= Convert.ToDateTime("20110101000000") &&
                     a.arrivalDate <= Convert.ToDateTime("20110131000000"));
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me that you want to compare dates, not strings.

`"20110101000000"` is a string, not a date.

`new DateTime(2011, 01, 01)` is a date.

```
var descriptions = from a in db.Descriptions           
                   where a.ID == 12
                   &&    DateTime.Parse(a.arrivalDate) >= new DateTime(2011,1,1)
                   &&    DateTime.Parse(a.arrivalDate) <= new DateTime(2011,1,31)
                   select a;
```

Comment: a.arrivalDate and "20110101000000", both are string. Your solution works fine if a.arrivalDate is of date type.

Comment: In that case, use one of the DateTime.Parse functions to convert arrivalDate to a DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

String class does not override >= or <=.  You need to use the static String.Compare(string, string) method.