# Dynamic Linq where statement with compare date as string

Tags: c#, linq

I need to build a dynamic where statement but I'm stuck with converting a `DateTime` to a string. Please look at my code and advise on how to compare `DateTime` type as string.

```
foreach (var f in filter.filters)
{
    if (f.Key.ToLower().Contains("date") || f.Key.ToLower().Contains("time"))
    {
        queryWhere += "CONVERT(VARCHAR(25)," + f.Key + ",126).Contains(\"" + f.Value + "\") AND ";
    }
    else
    {
        queryWhere += f.Key + ".Contains(\"" + f.Value + "\") AND ";
    }
}

return queryWhere = queryWhere.Remove(queryWhere.Length - 5);
```

Definition of Filter object:

```
public class Filter
{
    public string orderby { get; set; } = "Id";
    public Dictionary<string, string> filters { get; set; }
}
```

Filter object in JSON

```
{
   "orderby": "Id",
"filters": {
    "Status": "OK",
    "CreateDate" : "2016-02"
},}
```

Content of var queryWhere:

```
"Status.Contains(\"OK\") AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),CreateDate,126).Contains(\"2016-02\")"
```

ParseException Error:

> An exception of type 'System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException' occurred in System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: No applicable method 'VARCHAR' exists in type 'ServersViewModel'

I've changed from `CONVERT()` to `.ToString()` but I've got WARN

```
queryWhere += f.Key + ".ToString().Contains(\"" + f.Value + "\") AND ";
```

> warn:`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryCompilationCont
>   extFactory[8]`
>      The LINQ expression `'[srv].CreateDate.ToString().Contains("2016-02")'` could
>      not be translated and will be evaluated locally. To configure this warning    use the DbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings API (event id    'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning'). ConfigureWarnings can be used   when overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or using AddDbContext on the    application service provider.

Any Idea?

Comment: can you give example code and the output

Comment: Please check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535560/linq-compare-string-date

Comment: @Kevin I've updated my question.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing LINQ and SQL in the same statement. `Status.Contains` is C#/LINQ and `CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), CreateDate, 126)` is SQL. Looks like you want to do something like what @VijaySingh linked to instead. You may also want to [edit] your question to indicate that you're ultimately parsing `queryWhere` as a LINQ Expression...

Comment: Don't do this. Use a date range: `>= 2016-02-01 && < 2016-03-01`.